# Как конвертировать число в биты

Tags: c#

Нужно конвертировать числа,вводимые в textbox в  4-битовое число  и выводить в другой textbox(например 1 = 0001, 3 = 0011)
Попытался реализовать это вот так

```
 string input = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
            int i = 0;
            string Key = "";
            while (input.Length > i)
            {
                string temp = Convert.ToString(input[i], 2);
                             Key += temp;
                i++;

            }

            textBox2.Text = Key;
```

В результате получаю 1 = 110001,3 = 110011 и т.д. Откуда появляются 2 единицы в начале и как от них избавится?

Comment: Строк или чисел, вижу строки, а читаю про числа. Странноватенько. Если строки то `str.Select(i => Convert.ToString(i, 2))` если реальные числа, то: `(byte)(num >> 8)` или `BitConverter.GetBytes(num)`

Comment: @And
Если я использую (byte)(num >> 8) то в ответе получаю нули вместо значений,а если BitConverter.GetBytes(num) то  System.Byte[] .  Пожалуйста,можете привести пример?

Comment: Что-что нужно сделать??  `Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);` ясности не добавляет.  `110001b` - это ASCII-код **символа** "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitConverter.GetBytes(int) - конвертируй в байт.
А дальше так же конвертируй в строку

Comment: Получаю  System.Byte[] в ответе. Можете на примере применение показать ,пожалуйста?

Comment: Уже был подобный вопрос, можете потестить на [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318933/c-sharp-int-to-byte) коде: